# Multiple Providers with OmniAuth and Token Expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, twitter, omniauth

Using this [guide to manage multiple providers](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers) I designed my Rails app to handle both Twitter and Facebook login.  It does this by creating a separate model **Identity** that stores the Twitter / Facebook uid and associates it with a user on my site.

I'm also creating a companion mobile application that should authenticate users based on the uid passed back by Facebook or Twitter.

The issue is that Facebook and Twitter uids expire after a certain amount of time.  Since I use the uid to determine the user that's logging in, I was wondering how to deal with uid expiration.  **How do you manage expiring uids from Twitter and Facebook in a Rails app?**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was getting authorization tokens mixed up - the access token on facebook expires, but the UID stays the same, so there isn't any issue!